# Insert a dict into a sql table

Tags: python, sql, json, postgresql, request

i wanted to insert some data into my sql but having trouble because there is alot of columns so i would have to write alot of parameters after VALUE. I have a table with all attributes from the json file and a player_id which i add myself

```
#Gamelogs for players and Teams
import requests
import json
import psycopg2

# Connect to your postgres DB
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=NBA user=postgres password=********")

# Open a cursor to perform database operations
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE player_logs("player_id" int,"GameId" int,"Date" int,"Team" VARCHAR(10),"Opponent" VARCHAR(10),"Minutes" int,"Arc3Assists" int,"Arc3FGA" int,"Arc3Frequency" int,"AssistPoints" int,"Assists" int,"AtRimAssists" int,"AtRimFG3AFrequency" int,"Avg2ptShotDistance" int,"Avg3ptShotDistance" int,"BadPassOutOfBoundsTurnovers" int,"BadPassSteals" int,"BadPassTurnovers" int,"Corner3FGA" int,"Corner3Frequency" int,"DeadBallTurnovers" int,"DefArc3ReboundPct" int,"DefFGReboundPct" int,"DefPoss" int,"DefRebounds" int,"DefThreePtReboundPct" int,"DefThreePtRebounds" int,"EfgPct" int,"FG2A" int,"FG2M" int,"FG3A" int,"FG3APct" int,"FTA" int,"Fg2Pct" int,"FirstChancePoints" int,"Fouls" int,"FoulsDrawn" int,"FtPoints" int,"LiveBallTurnoverPct" int,"LiveBallTurnovers" int,"LongMidRangeAccuracy" int,"LongMidRangeAssists" int,"LongMidRangeFGA" int,"LongMidRangeFGM" int,"LongMidRangeFrequency" int,"Loose Ball Fouls" int,"LostBallTurnovers" int,"NonHeaveArc3FGA" int,"OffFGReboundPct" int,"OffPoss" int,"OffRebounds" int,"OffShortMidRangeReboundPct" int,"OffTwoPtReboundPct" int,"OffTwoPtRebounds" int,"OnDefRtg" int,"OnOffRtg" int,"PenaltyArc3FGA" int,"PenaltyArc3Frequency" int,"PenaltyDefPoss" int,"PenaltyEfgPct" int,"PenaltyFG2A" int,"PenaltyFG2M" int,"PenaltyFG3A" int,"PenaltyFg2Pct" int,"PenaltyOffPoss" int,"PenaltyOffPossExcludingTakeFouls" int,"PenaltyOffPossPct" int,"PenaltyPoints" int,"PenaltyPointsExcludingTakeFouls" int,"PenaltyPointsPct" int,"PenaltyShotQualityAvg" int,"PenaltyTsPct" int,"PenaltyTurnovers" int,"Period2Fouls2Minutes" int,"Period3Fouls3Minutes" int,"PlusMinus" int,"Points" int,"PtsUnassisted2s" int,"Rebounds" int,"SecondChanceOffPoss" int,"SelfOReb" int,"SelfORebPct" int,"ShootingFouls" int,"ShootingFoulsDrawnPct" int,"ShortMidRangeAccuracy" int,"ShortMidRangeAssists" int,"ShortMidRangeFGA" int,"ShortMidRangeFGM" int,"ShortMidRangeFrequency" int,"ShortMidRangeOffReboundedPct" int,"ShotQualityAvg" int,"Steals" int,"ThreePtAssists" int,"TotalPoss" int,"TsPct" int,"Turnovers" int,"TwoPtAssists" int,"TwoPtShootingFoulsDrawn" int,"TwoPtShootingFoulsDrawnPct" int,"UnblockedLongMidRangeAccuracy" int,"UnblockedShortMidRangeAccuracy" int,"Usage" int,"Arc3Accuracy" int,"Arc3FGM" int,"Arc3PctAssisted" int,"Assisted2sPct" int,"Assisted3sPct" int,"AtRimAccuracy" int,"AtRimFGA" int,"AtRimFGM" int,"AtRimFrequency" int,"AtRimOffReboundedPct" int,"AtRimPctBlocked" int,"Blocked2s" int,"BlockedShortMidRange" int,"Blocks" int,"BlocksRecoveredPct" int,"Corner3Assists" int,"DefAtRimReboundPct" int,"DefLongMidRangeReboundPct" int,"DefShortMidRangeReboundPct" int,"DefTwoPtReboundPct" int,"DefTwoPtRebounds" int,"FG2APctBlocked" int,"FG3M" int,"Fg2aBlocked" int,"Fg3Pct" int,"LongMidRangeOffReboundedPct" int,"LostBallSteals" int,"NonHeaveArc3Accuracy" int,"NonHeaveArc3FGM" int,"NonHeaveFg3Pct" int,"NonPutbacksAssisted2sPct" int,"NonShootingFoulsDrawn" int,"NonShootingPenaltyNonTakeFoulsDrawn" int,"OffLongMidRangeReboundPct" int,"Offensive Fouls Drawn" int,"PenaltyArc3Accuracy" int,"PenaltyArc3FGM" int,"PenaltyAtRimAccuracy" int,"PenaltyAtRimFGA" int,"PenaltyAtRimFGM" int,"PenaltyAtRimFrequency" int,"PenaltyFG3M" int,"PenaltyFg3Pct" int,"PenaltyFtPoints" int,"PtsAssisted2s" int,"PtsAssisted3s" int,"PtsPutbacks" int,"PtsUnassisted3s" int,"RecoveredBlocks" int,"SecondChanceArc3FGA" int,"SecondChanceArc3Frequency" int,"SecondChanceEfgPct" int,"SecondChanceFG2A" int,"SecondChanceFG2M" int,"SecondChanceFG3A" int,"SecondChanceFg2Pct" int,"SecondChancePoints" int,"SecondChancePointsPct" int,"SecondChanceShotQualityAvg" int,"SecondChanceTsPct" int,"ShortMidRangePctAssisted" int,"ShortMidRangePctBlocked" int,"ThreePtShootingFoulsDrawn" int,"ThreePtShootingFoulsDrawnPct" int,"UnblockedArc3Accuracy" int,"UnblockedAtRimAccuracy" int,"OffArc3ReboundPct" int,"OffThreePtReboundPct" int,"OffThreePtRebounds" int,"Offensive Fouls" int,"Corner3Accuracy" int,"Corner3FGM" int,"ThreePtOffReboundedPct" int,"UnblockedCorner3Accuracy" int,"DefFTReboundPct" int,"FTDefRebounds" int,"Technical Free Throw Trips" int,"BlockedAtRim" int,"LostBallOutOfBoundsTurnovers" int,"OffAtRimReboundPct" int,"BlockedLongMidRange" int,"Charge Fouls Drawn" int,"LongMidRangePctAssisted" int,"NonShootingPenaltyNonTakeFouls" int,"SecondChanceTurnovers" int,"Travels" int,"SecondChanceAtRimFGA" int,"SecondChanceAtRimFrequency" int,"Clear Path Fouls" int,"DefCorner3ReboundPct" int,"HeaveAttempts" int,"LongMidRangePctBlocked" int,"2pt And 1 Free Throw Trips" int,"AtRimPctAssisted" int,"Period3Fouls4Minutes" int,"Period4Fouls4Minutes" int,"Charge Fouls" int,"Loose Ball Fouls Drawn" int,"PeriodOTFouls4Minutes" int,"SecondChanceAtRimAccuracy" int,"SecondChanceAtRimFGM" int,"PenaltyCorner3FGA" int,"PenaltyCorner3Frequency" int,"Corner3PctAssisted" int,"SecondChanceFtPoints" int,"OffCorner3ReboundPct" int,"SecondChanceArc3Accuracy" int,"SecondChanceArc3FGM" int,"SecondChanceFG3M" int,"SecondChanceFg3Pct" int,"3pt And 1 Free Throw Trips" int,"Defensive 3 Seconds Violations" int,"Period4Fouls5Minutes" int,"StepOutOfBoundsTurnovers" int,"Period1Fouls2Minutes"int)')
x = 'https://api.pbpstats.com/get-all-players-for-league/nba'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Chrome/88.0.4324.190'}
jsonData1 = requests.get(x, headers=headers).json() # Player id and name

EntityId = json.loads(json.dumps(jsonData1)[12:-1])
SeasonType = {'R':'Regular+Season','P':'Playoff+Season','A':'All'}
EntityType = {'P':'Player','T':'Team'}
Season = {
            '2008-09',
            '2009-10',
            '2010-11',
            '2011-12',
            '2012-13',
            '2013-14',
            '2014-15',
            '2015-16',
            '2016-17',
            '2017-18',
            '2018-19',
            '2019-20',
            '2020-21'
            }
def log (S:Season,ST:SeasonType,EI:EntityId,ET:EntityType):
    url = 'https://api.pbpstats.com/get-game-logs/nba'
    payload = {
                'Season': S,
                'SeasonType': ST,
                'EntityId': EI,
                'EntityType': ET
                }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    if r == {'error': 'no results'} :
        return()
    else :
        for c in r['multi_row_table_data']:
            j = {'Player_id':EI} 
            c.update(j)
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO player_log (Player_id,GameId,Date,Team,Opponent,Minutes,Arc3Assists,Arc3FGA,Arc3Frequency,AssistPoints,Assists,AtRimAssists,AtRimFG3AFrequency,Avg2ptShotDistance,Avg3ptShotDistance,BadPassOutOfBoundsTurnovers,BadPassSteals,BadPassTurnovers,Corner3FGA,Corner3Frequency,DeadBallTurnovers,DefArc3ReboundPct,DefFGReboundPct,DefPoss,DefRebounds,DefThreePtReboundPct,DefThreePtRebounds,EfgPct,FG2A,FG2M,FG3A,FG3APct,FTA,Fg2Pct,FirstChancePoints,Fouls,FoulsDrawn,FtPoints,LiveBallTurnoverPct,LiveBallTurnovers,LongMidRangeAccuracy,LongMidRangeAssists,LongMidRangeFGA,LongMidRangeFGM,LongMidRangeFrequency,Loose_Ball_Fouls,LostBallTurnovers,NonHeaveArc3FGA,OffFGReboundPct,OffPoss,OffRebounds,OffShortMidRangeReboundPct,OffTwoPtReboundPct,OffTwoPtRebounds,OnDefRtg,OnOffRtg,PenaltyArc3FGA,PenaltyArc3Frequency,PenaltyDefPoss,PenaltyEfgPct,PenaltyFG2A,PenaltyFG2M,PenaltyFG3A,PenaltyFg2Pct,PenaltyOffPoss,PenaltyOffPossExcludingTakeFouls,PenaltyOffPossPct,PenaltyPoints,PenaltyPointsExcludingTakeFouls,PenaltyPointsPct,PenaltyShotQualityAvg,PenaltyTsPct,PenaltyTurnovers,Period2Fouls2Minutes,Period3Fouls3Minutes,PlusMinus,Points,PtsUnassisted2s,Rebounds,SecondChanceOffPoss,SelfOReb,SelfORebPct,ShootingFouls,ShootingFoulsDrawnPct,ShortMidRangeAccuracy,ShortMidRangeAssists,ShortMidRangeFGA,ShortMidRangeFGM,ShortMidRangeFrequency,ShortMidRangeOffReboundedPct,ShotQualityAvg,Steals,ThreePtAssists,TotalPoss,TsPct,Turnovers,TwoPtAssists,TwoPtShootingFoulsDrawn,TwoPtShootingFoulsDrawnPct,UnblockedLongMidRangeAccuracy,UnblockedShortMidRangeAccuracy,Usage,Arc3Accuracy,Arc3FGM,Arc3PctAssisted,Assisted2sPct,Assisted3sPct,AtRimAccuracy,AtRimFGA,AtRimFGM,AtRimFrequency,AtRimOffReboundedPct,AtRimPctBlocked,Blocked2s,BlockedShortMidRange,Blocks,BlocksRecoveredPct,Corner3Assists,DefAtRimReboundPct,DefLongMidRangeReboundPct,DefShortMidRangeReboundPct,DefTwoPtReboundPct,DefTwoPtRebounds,FG2APctBlocked,FG3M,Fg2aBlocked,Fg3Pct,LongMidRangeOffReboundedPct,LostBallSteals,NonHeaveArc3Accuracy,NonHeaveArc3FGM,NonHeaveFg3Pct,NonPutbacksAssisted2sPct,NonShootingFoulsDrawn,NonShootingPenaltyNonTakeFoulsDrawn,OffLongMidRangeReboundPct,Offensive_Fouls_Drawn,PenaltyArc3Accuracy,PenaltyArc3FGM,PenaltyAtRimAccuracy,PenaltyAtRimFGA,PenaltyAtRimFGM,PenaltyAtRimFrequency,PenaltyFG3M,PenaltyFg3Pct,PenaltyFtPoints,PtsAssisted2s,PtsAssisted3s,PtsPutbacks,PtsUnassisted3s,RecoveredBlocks,SecondChanceArc3FGA,SecondChanceArc3Frequency,SecondChanceEfgPct,SecondChanceFG2A,SecondChanceFG2M,SecondChanceFG3A,SecondChanceFg2Pct,SecondChancePoints,SecondChancePointsPct,SecondChanceShotQualityAvg,SecondChanceTsPct,ShortMidRangePctAssisted,ShortMidRangePctBlocked,ThreePtShootingFoulsDrawn,ThreePtShootingFoulsDrawnPct,UnblockedArc3Accuracy,UnblockedAtRimAccuracy,OffArc3ReboundPct,OffThreePtReboundPct,OffThreePtRebounds,Offensive_Fouls,Corner3Accuracy,Corner3FGM,ThreePtOffReboundedPct,UnblockedCorner3Accuracy,DefFTReboundPct,FTDefRebounds,Technical_Free_Throw_Trips,BlockedAtRim,LostBallOutOfBoundsTurnovers,OffAtRimReboundPct,BlockedLongMidRange,Charge_Fouls_Drawn,LongMidRangePctAssisted,NonShootingPenaltyNonTakeFouls,SecondChanceTurnovers,Travels,SecondChanceAtRimFGA,SecondChanceAtRimFrequency,Clear_Path_Fouls,DefCorner3ReboundPct,HeaveAttempts,LongMidRangePctBlocked,"2pt_And_1_Free_Throw_Trips",AtRimPctAssisted,Period3Fouls4Minutes,Period4Fouls4Minutes,Charge_Fouls,Loose_Ball_Fouls_Drawn,PeriodOTFouls4Minutes,SecondChanceAtRimAccuracy,SecondChanceAtRimFGM,PenaltyCorner3FGA,PenaltyCorner3Frequency,Corner3PctAssisted,SecondChanceFtPoints,OffCorner3ReboundPct,SecondChanceArc3Accuracy,SecondChanceArc3FGM,SecondChanceFG3M,SecondChanceFg3Pct,"3pt_And_1_Free_Throw_Trips",Defensive_3_Seconds_Violations,Period4Fouls5Minutes,StepOutOfBoundsTurnovers,Period1Fouls2Minutes) VALUES', 
                        c)
    return()    



y=log('2020-21','Regular+Season','101108','Player')

        
conn.commit()    
conn.close()
cur.close()
```

So was wondering if i could insert the data so it matched with the key and the column name. So the table and dict isnt order the same way either if it makes a difference.

Comment: Why not create a JSON field in your postgres schema and convert the dict to a JSON string and insert it that way?  Once the data is in postgres, you can return the fields within a JSON object like: `SELECT data ->> 'Player_id' AS player_id FROM table`

Comment: are quite new to it so dont now what options there is

Comment: Alternatively, check out this post to see an example of how to insert a dict into a postgres table, where the keys of the dict are the column names, and the values of the dict are the values to be inserted into the table. This only works if the keys in your dict match the keys in your postgres table. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39208540/3420371

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple to do by adopting two helper libraries: pandas and preql.

You can use pandas to load the json into a single dataframe, and then use preql to import it into the database.

Here is runnable code demonstrating how to do it:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from preql import Preql

headers = {'user-agent': 'Chrome/88.0.4324.190'}

def log(S,ST,EI,ET):
    url = 'https://api.pbpstats.com/get-game-logs/nba'
    payload = {
                'Season': S,
                'SeasonType': ST,
                'EntityId': EI,
                'EntityType': ET
                }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    if r == {'error': 'no results'} :
        return
    else:
        return [{'Player_id':EI, **d} for d in r['multi_row_table_data']]


rows=log('2020-21','Regular+Season','101108','Player')
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rows)
print("Dataframe shape:", df.shape) # (50, 218)
        

p = Preql()     # For postgres use: p = Preql("postgres://user:pass@server")
p.import_pandas(my_table=df)

print('SQL columns:', p('count(columns(my_table))'))       # 219 - includes id
print('SQL rows:', p('count(my_table)'))                   # 50
```

Note that this code example is currently using Python's built-in Sqlite, but you can easily make it work with postgres by providing Preql with the postgres URL, as the comment shows.

Install them with `pip install pandas preql-lang`

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best solution, but I wrote a small function that just converts to SQL statement.

```
def insert_into_table_query(table, data):
    col_names = list(data.keys())
    task = tuple(data.values())

    col_str = ', '.join(str(item) for item in col_names)
    col_str = '(' + col_str + ')'

    value_str = ', '.join('%s' for item in task)
    value_str = '(' + value_str + ');'

    sql = 'INSERT INTO {tn} '.format(tn=table) + col_str + ' VALUES ' + value_str

    return (sql, task)
```

Comment: Is it neccesary that dict and table is ordered the same?

Comment: What about SQL injection?

Comment: No, the dictionary and tables do not need to be ordered the same. As long as the values in your SQL statement match the column names. 

@Frank Heikens: I'm not an expert, learning myself. But from my understanding, the syntax I have above is safe from SQL Injection. (http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples)

When I execute my code, I get 

    query = 'INSERT INTO TableX (tablex_id, user_id) VALUES (%s, %s);' # str
    task = (9, 3) # tuple
    db.cursor.execute(query, task)




(http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples)